# Retrieving a data property on an Angular2 route regardless of the level of route nesting using ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have defined a number of routes as follows:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: {titleKey: 'homeTitle'}},
  {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent, data: {titleKey: 'SIGNUP_FORM.TITLE'}},
  {path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent, data: {titleKey: 'SIGNIN_FORM.TITLE'}},
  {path: 'sendpasswordresetinformation', component: SendPasswordResetInformationComponent},
  {path: 'password/reset/:userAccountToken', component: PasswordResetComponent},
  {
    path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
    {path: '', component: DashboardSummaryComponent},
    {
      path: 'message', children: [
      {path: '', component: MessageSummaryComponent, data: {titleKey: 'MESSAGE_LIST.TITLE'}},
      {path: 'conversation/:otherId', component: MessageConversationComponent, data: {titleKey: 'XXX'}}]
    },
    {
      path: 'useraccount', component: UserAccountComponent, children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UserAccountSummaryComponent,
        data: {titleKey: 'XXX'},
        resolve: {
          userAccount: UserAccountResolve
        }
      },
      {path: 'address', component: UserAccountAddressComponent, data: {titleKey: 'ADDRESS_FORM.TITLE'}},
      {path: 'email', component: UserAccountEmailComponent, data: {titleKey: 'EMAIL_FORM.TITLE'}},
      {
        path: 'emailnotification',
        component: UserAccountEmailNotificationComponent,
        data: {titleKey: 'EMAIL_NOTIFICATION_FORM.TITLE'}
      },
      {path: 'firstname', component: UserAccountFirstNameComponent, data: {titleKey: 'FIRST_NAME_FORM.TITLE'}},
      {path: 'password', component: UserAccountPasswordComponent, data: {titleKey: 'PASSWORD_FORM.TITLE'}}]
    }]
  }];
```

Some of the routes are children of others.

I would like to find a way to retrieve the `titleKey` property on `data` regardless of whether the route is a top level route or the child of another.

Here is what I have tried:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
              private sessionService: SessionService,
              private titleService: Title,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    let userLang = 'fr';
    translate.use(userLang);
    moment.locale(userLang);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.reloadPersonalInfo();
  }

  setTitle($event) { 
    this.translate.get(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['titleKey'])
     .subscribe(translation=>this.titleService.setTitle(translation));
  }
}
```

`this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['titleKey']` is `undefined`.

Can someone please advise how to retrieve a property on route `data` regardless of the level of nesting of the route?

**edit**: After reading the official [angular documentation about ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html), I tried to use the `map` operator on the data property of the `ActivatedRoute` instance as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
              <section class="container-fluid row Conteneur">
                 <appNavbar></appNavbar>
                 <section class="container">
                    <router-outlet (activate)="setTitle($event)"></router-outlet>
                 </section>
              </section>
              <section class="container-fluid">  
                <appFooter></appFooter>
              </section>
              `,
  directives: [NavbarComponent, FooterComponent, SigninComponent, HomeComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
              private sessionService: SessionService,
              private titleService: Title,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    let userLang = 'fr';
    translate.use(userLang);
    moment.locale(userLang);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.reloadPersonalInfo();
  }

  setTitle($event) {
    this.activatedRoute.data.map(data=>data['titleKey'])
      .do(key=>console.log(key))
      .switchMap(key=>this.translate.get(key))
      .subscribe(translation=>this.titleService.setTitle(translation));
  }
}
```

and yet `key` is always undefined...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I stumbled on a nice tutorial with a clean solution: https://toddmotto.com/dynamic-page-titles-angular-2-router-events.

Here is what I finally came up with using the solution from the above tutorial and using the [ng2 translate service](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) in order to convert the `titleKeys` specified in my route data into proper labels:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['../styles/bootstrap.scss'],
  template: `<section class="container-fluid row Conteneur">
                 <app-navbar></app-navbar>
                 <section class="container">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                 </section>
              </section>
              <section class="container-fluid">  
                <app-footer></app-footer>
              </section>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
              private sessionSigninService: SessionSigninService,
              private titleService: Title,
              private router: Router,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    let userLang = 'fr';
    translate.use(userLang);
    moment.locale(userLang);
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
      .map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
      })
      .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
      .mergeMap(route => route.data)
      .mergeMap(data => this.translate.get(data['titleKey']))
      .subscribe(translation => this.titleService.setTitle(translation));
  }
}
```

Comment: This both very powerful with what can be accomplished and utterly ridiculous with the amount of code needed.

Answer (score 6):

We had this same problem. We decided to go about it another way. Instead of trying to listen for the data emits on the ActivatedRoute, we subscribe to the `events` Observable on the router itself:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from "@angular/router";

declare var module: any;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "app-layout",
    templateUrl: "main-layout.component.html"
})
export class LayoutComponent {
    titleKey: string;

    constructor(private router: Router){}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events
            .filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
            .subscribe(() => {
                var root = this.router.routerState.snapshot.root;
                while (root) {
                    if (root.children && root.children.length) {
                        root = root.children[0];
                    } else if (root.data && root.data["titleKey"]) {
                        this.titleKey = root.data["titleKey"];
                        return;
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Note that we're using the value in a component that is used at the top level but needs the data from the deepest child route. You should be able to pretty easily convert this to a service that emits events whenever the `titleKey` changes value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had problems with the accepted answer's 'While' method in the pipe() stream (it crashed my app), so your solution has been implemented here as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

You may try below in `AppComponent` ,

```
   constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
          private sessionService: SessionService,
          private titleService: Title,
          private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

      this.router.events.subscribe((arg) => {
         if(arg instanceof NavigationEnd) { 
           console.log(this.getTitle(this.activatedRoute.snapshot));
         }
      });
   }

   getTitle = (snapshot) => {
     if(!!snapshot && !!snapshot.children && !!snapshot.children.length > 0){
      return this.getTitle(snapshot.children[0]);
     }
    else if(!!snapshot.data && !!snapshot.data['titleKey']){
      return snapshot.data['titleKey'];
    }
    else{
      return '';
    }
   }
```

seems little hacky but works.

**Old**

You may try below,

```
{
  path: 'conversation/:otherId', 
  component: MessageConversationComponent, 
  data: {titleKey: 'XXX'},
  // add below resolve
  resolve: {
            titleKey: MessageConversationResolve
  }      
}
```

add a new service **MessageConversationResolve.ts** and add it appropriately in providers.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve,ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }             from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AdminDetailResolve implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private titleService: Title) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    // route.data will give you the titleKey property
    // console.log(route.data);
    // you may consume titleService here to setTitle

    return route.data.titleKey;
 }
}
```

Below is angular version which supports above solution,

`Angular 2 version : 2.0.0-rc.5`

`Angular Router version : 3.0.0-rc.1`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. Umm. That is not what `resolves` are meant for. I am just dealing with simple keys here. Isn't it overkill to use `resolves` here?

Comment: the simplest solution is to get the data from within the child component itself, but i guess you don't want to inject title service in the child component, if that is not the case you may use `this.route.data.subscribe(data => { console.log(data);  })` inside the child component and get the data easily. Hope this helps!!

Comment: I am seeking to minimize duplication and I'd rather not have the listener i.e. `setTitle` repeated over all my components. I think it should be in only **one** place.

Comment: how is setTitle triggered? when you change route? or a button click?

Comment: When the route is activated by the `(activate)` event.

Comment: See source code for `router-outlet` [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/6db27153ef04dabdf479fed64dc797653196867b/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts#L46) pointing to `activate` event.

Comment: @balteo were you able to try this?

Comment: Hi Madhu, I was rather looking for less hacky solution. But I was told lately that there is not a clean solution yet available. I will post here when if and when I am given with a clean solution.