# Get Custom Route Data from lazy loaded route in top level component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 5 and I seem to not be able to get data from ActivatedRoute using methods stated in other answers to my question.

app.routes.ts

```
export const AppRoutes = [
    {
        path : '',
        component: HomeView,
        pathMatch: 'full', data: {key: 'home', label: 'Home'}},
    {
        path : 'about',
        loadChildren: './+about/about.module#AboutModule'
    },
    {
        path : 'account/:id',
        loadChildren: './+account/account.module#AccountModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: {key: 'account', label: 'My Account'}
    },
];
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ou-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../styles/main.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(event => {
            console.log('router events console... ', this.route);
        });
    }
}
```

I can't seem to get the data from the route under snapshot, root, children, firstChild, everything is null, or undefined

Comment: Why are you trying to console log `this.route`? Are you interested in something in particular?

Comment: I'm trying to get the data obj from the activated route. I wasn't finding anything in this.route.snapshot.data or route.firstChild, .children etc. so I consoled this.route to look at the whole activated route and it looks blank which leaves me to believe I'm not getting it correctly

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issue is that you are not *at* the route that you are trying to look at. You need to go through the child routes. There is an example here: [Retrieving a data property on an Angular2 route regardless of the level of route nesting using ActivatedRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877123/retrieving-a-data-property-on-an-angular2-route-regardless-of-the-level-of-route)

I was able to modify your code as follows using the info from the above link.

```
  router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
    .map(route  => {
      console.log(route.snapshot.data);
      while (route .firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
      return route;
    })
    .mergeMap(route => route.data)
    .subscribe(x => {
      console.log('router events console... ', x);
    });
```

With this code I was able to get this:

[image]

**Update:** With RxJs v5.5 and above

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
        .pipe(
            filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
            map(() => this.activatedRoute),
            map((route) => {
                while (route.firstChild) {
                    route = route.firstChild;
                }
                return route;
            }),
            mergeMap((route) => route.data))
        .subscribe((event) => console.log('router events console... ', event));
}
```

Comment: you are correct. thank you. I was able to get it running on stackblitz but not on my local project I'm working on.. so it must be something else.

Comment: Hi, @DeborahK, won't it work if I use map instead of subscribing. It's getting stuck when I'm trying to do that. Here is a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-right?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Since you are using a resolver, you don't have to use router events. The resolver already gives you what you need and you can dramatically simplify your code. I did an updated stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-guard-data-deborahk

Comment: @DeborahK your simplified solution has only worked for the root route in the module. It's not working for child routes.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem following this github issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11812

```
    this.router.events.subscribe((data) => {
        if (data instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
            console.log(data.state.root.firstChild.data);
        }
    });
```